# Permissions while deleting rows from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with rows having duplicate userId's. I am trying to delete the row's as

`delete from  table_name where userId=123`

This query works only if I give both select and delete permissions to the database. Is is compulsory to grant the select permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DELETE permissions are required on the target table. SELECT permissions are also required if the statement contains a WHERE clause. Here is link from microsoft, refer permission section

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx

Comment: Do you know why it is so? Why is the *SELECT* permission required in addition to the *DELETE* permission while deleting rows, if the *DELETE* statement contains a *WHERE* clause?

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but my guess is, sql server engine might be doing a SELECT (which requires select permission) first to get the rows which satisfy the criteria, then execute DELETE.

Comment: I did find some information regarding this here                  http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2011/10/17/is-the-select-permission-checked-in-an-update-statement.aspx